# Can I implment this with Wicket table components?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, wicket

I have a below requirements, I would like to know how feasible it is to implement this with Wicket table components.

1. A web page should contain a table initially with one row.
2. On the bottom of the table there should be some links to add row in AJAX way(No page refresh)
3. I should be able to clone a selected row when I click a link on the bottom of the table.
4. Some of the table cells should be editable
5. Each row should contain a button on the last row, when I click this I should be able to send the row values to server and update some cells. (In ajax way)

I know Wicket has something called "AjaxFallbackDataTable". Is this solves all these requirements? if not are there any other table implementations available? And is there any JQuery plugin available for this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do all of this with Wicket components, but I don't know of a specific table implementation that covers all of this.

There are code examples in [Wicket Library repeater examples](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/repeater/) that are worth looking through.